# Formar media piramide con asteriscos - solo usando un asterisco (bucle for - bucle while)

Tags: php, bucle-for, while

Hola estoy tratando de realizar media piramide con un solo asterisco usando ambos bucles while y for ya que el ejercicio me pide que realize 2 piramides con cada tipo de bucle, he tratado de hacer algo similar con ambos pero tan solo me muestra una unica linea, que estoy realizando incorrectamente ?

Ejemplo de lo que pide el ejercicio:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
```

Codigo con while:

```
<?php

$num=1;
$num2=1;
$fila= 6;
$ast ="*";

while($num<=$fila){
    $resultado = $num++;
    if($num2<=$resultado){
        $resultado++;
            echo $ast." ";
        }
    echo "";
}
```

codigo con for:

```
<?php

$num=0;
$num2=0;
$ast ="*";

for ($num;$num<6;$num++){
    for($num2;$num2<$num;$num2++){
        echo $ast;
    }
    echo "";
}
```

Muchisimas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay esos ejercicios que nos dejan en la escuela! que al final de cuentas no sirven de nada, pero bueno, crea dos funciones y a cada una le pasas el numero de filas de tu media piramide.

```
function crearPiramideConFor ($filas) {
    $cadena = null;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $filas; $i++) {
        for ($h = $i; $h <= $i; $h++) {
            $cadena .= "*";
        }
        echo $cadena."<br />";
    }
}

function crearPiramideConWhile ($filas) {
    $cadena = null;
    while($filas){
        $cadena .= "*";
        $filas--;
        echo $cadena."<br />";
    }
    
}
```

Solo manda a llamar cualquier funcion y le pasas como parametro el numero de filas

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! llevaba ya muchos intentos no sabía como colocarlo correctamente, tengo una duda porque el " .= " ? es lo mismo que  "+=" ?

Comment: Como estamos concatenando un string lo ideal es poner .= te dejo una guia para que puedas investigar mas a fondo: [Operadores de Asignacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.assignment.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Acabo de empezar con el php hace unos dias, vengo de java y hay muchas cosas que aún me quedan por ver.